# How to change position of the submit button inside a form?

Tags: html, css

**My HTML code:**

```css
body{
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(95, 112, 160, 0.479);
}

h2{
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#details{
  display: block;
  background-color:rgba(28, 117, 190, 0.726);
}

#back{
  font-size:20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#go{ 
  font-size:20px;
  margin-left: 800px;
  border-radius: 8px;  
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h2>Please finalize your details</h2>
    <form id="details" action=database_registration.php method="post" class="form">

        Full name: <strong name="name_1" value=""></strong><br><br>
        ID No:<strong name="org_number_1" value=""></strong><br><br>
        Mobile No:<strong name="ph_number_1" value=""></strong><br><br>

        E-mail: <strong name="email_1"></strong><br><br>
        ID Card: <img src="" alt="preview" name="image" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" value=""><br><br>

        <button id="go" style="background-color: whitesmoke">It's correct</button>

    </form>
    <button id="back" style="background-color: whitesmoke" onclick="goback()">Something's wrong</button>
    <p id="response"></p>
</body>
```

As you can see, the button `It's correct` is inside the blue display block. I want to re-position it a little below. Please help me fix this.

[image]

I want both the buttons to be outside the blue display and at the same height.

Comment: what you are doing here, is invalid HTML. Form needs to have `<label>` or `<input>` as direct child. Also, if you use 2x `<br>`after each other, you do somethign wrong. Thats what you have `margin-bottom` for. also, if you want a button to be displayed outside of a container, then simply dont put it inside a container at your HTML

Comment: @tacoshy this is incorrect. [Any flow content is a valid child of `form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). Though the use of `label` is very much recomended. Your comments regarding `br` are spot on though. Also you are correct that the form is useless without `input` elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button is used to submit the form, it needs to be inside the form.

You also have a distinct lack form elements which I have addressed.

Encapsulate all but the buttons in a `filedset`. Then create a specific `div` to hold the buttons and use `flex` and `justify-content` to position the buttons.

```css
body {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(95, 112, 160, 0.479);
}

h2 {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#details label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

#details fieldset {
  background-color: rgba(28, 117, 190, 0.726);
  border: none;
}

#details input {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0.5em;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.buttons button {
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>Please finalize your details</h2>
  <form id="details" action=database_registration.php method="post" class="form">
    <fieldset>
      <label>Full name: <input name="name_1" value=""></label>
      <label>ID No:<input name="org_number_1" value=""></label>
      <label>Mobile No:<input name="ph_number_1" value=""></label>
      <label>E-mail: <input name="email_1"></label>
      <div>ID Card: <img src="" alt="preview" name="image" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" value=""></div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button id="back" style="background-color: whitesmoke" onclick="goback()">Something's wrong</button> <button id="go" style="background-color: whitesmoke">It's correct</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <p id="response"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

To put it below the blue box, you simply have to add `margin-bottom: (value);` and adjust a couple of things (see details below)

See the example below:

```css
body{
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgba(95, 112, 160, 0.479);
}

h2{
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#details{
    display: block;
    background-color:rgba(28, 117, 190, 0.726);
}

#back{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#go{ 
    font-size:20px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    border-radius: 8px;  
    margin-bottom: 800px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h2>Please finalize your details</h2>
    <form id="details" action=database_registration.php method="post" class="form">

        Full name: <strong name="name_1" value=""></strong><br><br>
        ID No:<strong name="org_number_1" value=""></strong><br><br>
        Mobile No:<strong name="ph_number_1" value=""></strong><br><br>
        
        E-mail: <strong name="email_1"></strong><br><br>
        ID Card: <img src="" alt="preview" name="image" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" value=""><br><br>

    </form>
    <button id="back" style="background-color: whitesmoke" onclick="goback()">Something's wrong</button>
    
    <button id="go" style="background-color: whitesmoke">It's correct</button>
    <p id="response"></p>
</body>
```

So there's a couple of things I changed, your `go` button HTML needed to be at the same position as the `back` button and I switched the position of that whole line in your HTML code. Second, I adjusted the `margin-left` since your button was way off. Also, I added `margin-bottom` to again adjust the positioning of your button. As per your request, you wanted it below the form in which this code accomplishes that task, but let me know if there is something else missing.

Comment: If the  `button` is used to submit the form, it should be encapsulated in the `form` element.